# DXA Breadcrumb - How it works?

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java

where we can find the documentation for DXA breadcrumb for java? 
How it works? How we have to configure?
Which classes and information is necessary?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to make your question more specific. Where have you looking, what is not working, what are you trying to-do. General documentation for DXA can be found at http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4

Comment: We are starting to implement Breadcrumb in DXA and we need some information to understand how it works and how to configure it. We only need general information to have a starting point.

Comment: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-7339801D-4D95-46B1-8EBC-4000FE282580 ?

Comment: And that's an Answer, Jarno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This are the steps that we did:

1. Create a Component based on Schema `Navigation configuration`
2. In the Pages that we want to see the breadcrumb, in the Component templates, link `Breadcrumb [Tools]` CT to the Component created in the previous step
3. In The jsp for our PT add `<dxa:region name="Tools" />` (region specified in the Breadcrumb CT)
4. Modify `breadcrumb.jspx` to adapt the html to our layout
5. Publish `navigation.json`
6. Publish the pages that we created

Internally, is using `NavigationController` to access to the `navigation.json` and resolve all the links that we need to mount the breadcrumb.

Maybe this explanation is basic, but I think that is necessary for the teams that are starting with DXA.

Comment: I would add that it makes sense to include a breadcrumb via an include page, rather than add it directly on a Page, that way you can add a breadcrumb using a Page Template configuration and don't really have to have it available on every page (you will still need to publish each page using that PT since it changed). This is also what is done in the out of the box DXA example website, where the breadcrumb is added to the `Content Tools` include Page, which in turn is used in the `Content Page` Page Template.

Comment: +1 to Bart's point. Putting the breadcrumb on the page means more work for editors and less control for developers for if/when it changes.